# listings - How to format words of a external code file under a condition

Tags: formatting, listings, external-files

I'm using `listings` to put a external code file in my document. I'm trying to customize its appearance to identify when the first character of a word is a digit and then change the color of this specific word. I was thinking about using a `\if` condition inside the `\lstset`, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the code in an external file you can use something like

```
\lstinputlisting[language=awk]{yourcode.awk}
```

You can still modify the aspect of your listing preceding it with

```
\lstset{%
 extendedchars=true,%
 basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
 keywordstyle=\color{Brown}\bfseries,%
 commentstyle=\color{Blue}\sffamily,%
 showstringspaces=false,%
 numbers=left,%
 stepnumber=1,%
 numberstyle=\tiny,%
 xleftmargin=1em,%
 backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},%
 }
```

If you prefer including the code directly in your document try something like

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Octave]
function res = factorial(n)
  res = 1;
  for i = 1:n
     res = res * i;
  endfor
endfunction
\end{lstlistings}
```